# GWT History.replaceItem is behaving strange in compiled mode but works fine in superdev

Tags: gwt, browser-history

I came across a strange behavior (seems a bug) when calling History.replaceItem() that only happens in compiled code (not superdev) and not in every call, just in a specific place. For example, if I call replaceItem("Test"), instead of redirecting me to /mymodule#Test it redirects to mymodule/B074C219323C1E9000476B2275FF2790.cache.html##Test/ (regardless if issue event is true or false). I have no idea what to check or where to start from. Any clues?

Comment: A github repository with a minimal working project will be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was because I had this in my gwt config file:

```
<add-linker name="std"/>
```

I removed it and now it works fine.